# xUnit shared context by private static fields

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit, dispose

What disadvantages have an approach of [sharing context](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#constructor) by creating `private static` fields?

```cs
public class MyTests3 : IDisposable
{
    private static Mock<ILogger> _loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger>();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _loggerMock.Invocations.Clear();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Debug_OnInit_CalledOnce()
    {
        // arrange & act
        _loggerMock.Object.Debug("first");
        
        // assert
        _loggerMock.Verify(l => l.Debug(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
    }
    
    [Fact]
    public void Debug_OnExecute_CalledOnce()
    {
        // arrange & act
        _loggerMock.Object.Debug("second");
        
        // assert
        _loggerMock.Verify(l => l.Debug(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

The other question - should I call `Reset` for mock objects after the test is done?

Comment: Your "sharing context" link doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid sharing state between tests. It can create unwanted and unpredictable behavior, especially when your tests run in parallel.

It's one of the reason for the [prefer-helper-methods-to-setup-and-teardown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices#prefer-helper-methods-to-setup-and-teardown) best practice.

Comment: This is just a recomendation. As well as we shoud keep our tests [fast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices#characteristics-of-a-good-unit-test). So if I have multiple test cases I don't want to create objects again and allocate memory if I sure about their immutability.